# 2 viewports: 1 with weight paint and 1 with object mode - is that possible?

Tags: 3d-view

i would like to have 2 viewports, 1 with object mode and 1 with weight paint mode at the same time. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know: **No, because you cannot edit (paint) the weight and the object at the same time.**

**But** if you simply don't want to see the weight paint in the other viewport, just choose a shading mode, *Solid*, *Material Preview* or *Rendered* and under *Overlays* set the *Weight Paint* > *Opacity* to 0.

[image: overlays]

Comment: No this is not possible. Object modes are global to the object. Either you are in one mode. Or you are in another mode. Not in two modes simultaneously.

What you can do is to set up workspaces that enters automatically specific modes. This is for example done with the sculpt workspace.

Comment: That's what I said at the start, you cannot be in different modes at the same time.

Comment: Yes, cross posting. I added the bit with the workspace though.

Comment: It's not cross posting when you comment it on my post :D

Comment: Yeah, curious, why does my post appear under your answer? I posted it in reply to the question O_O . Either way, the answer is the important part.

Comment: @Tiles The problem with workspaces is, you have to switch between them. Then Chris could also switch simply between _Object Mode_ and _Weight Paint Mode_.